# Anchor tag href tel with number starting with 0

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a requirements where there is anchor tag and tel href is there. But issue is I have a number starting with 0 and it must be in dial pad. So let say a contact number is 02882550270, so it is omitting 0 here and just dialing 2882550270. Is there any way or external libraries which I use?

Below is my code

```
<a href="tel:02882550270">02882550270</a>
```

Comment: Did you try putting a `+` after `tel:+0`. I'm pretty sure the plus has to be there.

Comment: Here's a link with some advice on that: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/